# Disabling Prompt While reading .doc file

Tags: .net

How to disable prompt while opening word file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
Prompt is as follows:
Test.doc is locked for editing by another user.
Do you want to:
 .Open a read only copy
 .Create a local copy and merge your changes later.
 .Receive notification when the original copy is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to modify the document you could open it as read only through the word.document.open method, setting the third parameter to true.

If you do need to open it for editing you could code defensively by testing to see if there was a file lock on the word document before attempting to open it. An option to implement this might be to open the file in a filestream object for write access and trap an exception if thrown which would indicate you cannot edit it. You'd then use this information to decide whether to open readonly or for editing in your code.